# Windows 10 - How to turn off "This app has prevented you from shutting down"

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, default-settings, windows-10-pro

Windows 10 does not always shutdown because "an app is preventing you from shutting down". Is there a setting to force shutdown regardless of "potential save loss"? I don't care if I lose work. This has become a problem for me because sometimes I stand up and walk away, and I come back 3 hours later and my computer is still on...

[image]

Comment: Please understand that for a decade, Windows had a reputation for hanging on shutdown. This dialog is designed to prevent those hangs from happening, by having the user fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut, for example on your Desktop, to the command

```
shutdown /t 30 /s
```

and name it something description such as "Shutdown in 30 seconds".

As you'd expect, double-click the shortcut to run it. Your machine will shutdown after 30 seconds. Head to START and type `shutdown /a` if you didn't intend to do that!

Another useful shortcut is for a restart,

```
shutdown /t 30 /r
```

You can adjust the timeout up or down from 30 seconds as you like. (It must be non-zero; I tend to use 10 seconds as my "do it now" value.)

Comment: If a file is open as the post said , your shortcuts will not prevent the message . Files have to be saved first

Comment: Works for me. on Windows 10, 20H2. Going the GUI route triggers the warning page with the inevitable abandonment of shutdown. Going the CLI route gets what I want. My test rig was a clean start of Word, editing a document (without autosave), and then triggering shutdown

Comment: I should have been clearer. Forcing a shutdown will lose the contents of open files. That does not seem at all useful to me.

Comment: I have good reasons for using this. I would imagine the OP does, too

Comment: @roaima I've been messing with PowerShells `Stop-Computer` and there's a `-Force` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Click on Cancel, and then close both apps. If the files in the apps have been saved, it will not prevent shutdown.  Just be sure files are saved.

I see this and how I describe is how I handle this.

You do have to deal with the issue as it will wait for a response.

So when you shut down, watch for this and deal with it. Better to save files frequently.

Comment: I meant that I want this to be turned off completely (e.g. completely bypass the dialog). I know how to get past the check, I'm not that stupid.

Comment: I understand, but you need to save files. Otherwise you need to handle the message.

Comment: In other words, there's no way to force shutdown? What about PowerShell's `Stop-Computer`?

Comment: Any shutdown (short of a script to save and close) will result in this message if files have not been saved.

Comment: You cannot disable the dialog itself but you can address the reason it happens.  In the case of the example on the screenshot you have to close those two  programs

Comment: @Kolob Canyon - Please do not forget that you will be very unhappy if you succeed in forcing shutdown and losing your work.  Be sure to save your work.